# ng-blur works only if it is clicked inside the textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textbox where it can be written a value. If I delete that value and don't write anything in place, I want that when I click somewhere else that value to "come back" in the textbox.

Something works but not exactly how it shoud.

HTML part:

```
<input type="number" ng-blur="$ctrl.blur('max')" 
ng-change="$ctrl.updateY('max')" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}" 
ng-model="$ctrl.max">
```

JS part:

```
blur(which) {
    if(which === 'max') {
        if(!this.max) {
            this.max = this.maxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
updateY(which) {
    if(which === 'max') {
        if(this.max) {
            this.maxValue = this.max;
        }
    }
const maxNumber = Number(this.maxValue);
this.lineView.chart.axis.range({max: {y: maxNumber}, min: {y: maxNumber-100}});
}
```

As it is now, if I delete the value of the textbox and click somewhere else on the screen, the value is not written back in the textbox.

But it is written back if I click in the textbox after I delete it. I want to make it be re-written even if I click anywhere outside the textbox.

Is this possible?

Comment: Works fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/WjYXyp33FeeWaUnBSAHd?p=preview

Comment: I see, it looks the same as mine and works fine in the plunker. But for a reason I don't know, in my project it works only if I click in the textbox after I delete the text

Answer (score 1):

I could also see the "odd" behavior in that it only happened sometimes and not all the time.
To fix the issue, remove the

```
ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"
```

and it will work.